Running a C# .NET console app using HtmlAgilityPack that scrapes a webpage and loops appears to produce a memory leak. Where is the issue here?
When I run this C# console app code (using the HtmlAgilityPack open source project), memory usage starts to build up over time in what appears to be a memory leak, but I can't track it down, despite doing forced Garbage Collection, reusing objects, setting things to null, and clearing out information.
Where is the flaw in my code here? Or is this an issue with HtmlAgilityPack?
Things just grind to a halt after 10 minutes of this loop running. And this is on a system with 128 GB of RAM.
using HtmlAgilityPack;


internal class Program
{
    private static int setNum = 16020;
    static HtmlDocument doc = null;
    static HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ScrapeTypeYearName(setNum);

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine(); // Wait for the user to press Enter
    }

    public static void ScrapeTypeYearName(int setNum)
    {
        string setUrl = "https://www.tcdb.com/Checklist.cfm/sid/" + setNum;

        doc = web.Load(setUrl);

        // Process breadcrumb information
        string category = "";
        string year = "";
        string company = "";
        string setName = "";
        var breadcrumb = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='d-none d-md-block']/nav[@aria-label='breadcrumb']");
        if (breadcrumb != null)
        {
            var breadcrumbItems = breadcrumb.SelectNodes("./ol/li/a");
            if (breadcrumbItems != null && breadcrumbItems.Count >= 4)
            {
                category = breadcrumbItems[1].InnerText.Trim();
                year = breadcrumbItems[3].InnerText.Trim();
                Console.WriteLine("Category: " + category);
                Console.WriteLine("Year: " + year);

                var companyNode = breadcrumb.SelectSingleNode("following::h1[@class='site']");
                var setNode = breadcrumb.SelectSingleNode("following::h3[@class='site']");
                if (companyNode != null)
                {
                    company = companyNode.InnerText.Trim();
                    company = company.Replace(year, "").Trim();
                    Console.WriteLine("Company: " + company);
                }

                if (setNode != null)
                {
                    setName = setNode.InnerText.Trim();
                    Console.WriteLine("Set: " + setName);
                }
            }
        } 

        // Do stuff here with the 

        // Clear the main document to free up memory
        doc?.DocumentNode.RemoveAll();

        setNum += 1;
        if (setNum < 99999)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"");
            Console.WriteLine($"On set #: {setNum}");
            // Force garbage collection before the next recursive call
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            ScrapeTypeYearName(setNum);
        }
    }
}


You have a recursive method call to ScrapeTypeYearName(), is that intentional?

Yes, it increases the setNum by one and just reruns the function at the end. Is the in-function recursiveness causing this? I dont know why GC wouldn't clear out memory regardless.

The GC can only clear out managed memory that is no longer referenced. Are you sure that doc?.DocumentNode.RemoveAll() actually removes references?

The problem is that you call ScrapeTypeYearName() in a recursive fashion. Each call creates a new stack with new local variables of the method you are calling. This also means that all the "previous" method stacks are "put on hold", but are not deleted or "reclaimed" by the GC. You have the variables setUrl, category, year, company, setName and breadcrumb which are referencing objects in the heap. And you have these references in these variables for each method stack. And since you have a method call stack of 99999-16020=83979 method stacks and six variables holding potentially different objects in the heap, you eventually ran out of heap space.
There is no need for calling this method ScrapeTypeYearName() in a recursive manner. Remove the recursive call. A simple for loop outside this method should be just fine. The code could be as simple as:
for (int setNum=16020; setNum<99999; setNum++)
{
    ScrapeTypeYearName(setNum);
}


Ok thank you for explaining! I'll make sure to add a callback (or completion handler of some kind) before continuing in the loop, because I don't want 99999 web calls to happen all at once. I'll test again and see what happens.

Moved the loop outside and added async/await and that fixed it. Thanks so much for the help.
